# How to get the byte offset between `&str`

Tags: rust

I have two `&str` *pointing to the same string*, and I need to know the byte offset between them:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = "  bar";
    assert_eq!(offset(foo, foo.trim()), Some(2));

    let bar = "baz\nquz";
    let mut lines = bar.lines();
    assert_eq!(offset(bar, lines.next().unwrap()), Some(0));
    assert_eq!(offset(bar, lines.next().unwrap()), Some(4));

    assert_eq!(offset(foo, bar), None); // not a sub-string

    let quz = "quz".to_owned();
    assert_eq!(offset(bar, &quz), None); // not the same string, could also return `Some(4)`, I don't care
}
```

This is basically the same as `str::find`, but since the second slice is a sub-slice of the first, I would have hoped something faster. Also `str::find` won't work in the `lines()` case if several lines are identical.

I thought I could just use some pointer arithmetic to do that with something like `foo.trim().as_ptr() - foo.as_ptr()` but it turns out that `Sub` is not implemented on raw pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but it turns out that `Sub` is not implemented on raw pointers.

You can use the [`offset_from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.offset_from) method:

```
fn main() {
    let source = "hello, world";
    let a = &source[1..];
    let b = &source[5..];
    // I copied this unsafe code from Stack Overflow without
    // reading the text that told me how to know if this was safe
    let diff = unsafe { b.as_ptr().offset_from(a.as_ptr()) };
    println!("{diff}");
}
```

Please be sure to read the documentation for this method as it describes under what circumstances it will not cause undefined behavior.

In older versions of Rust, you can convert the pointer to a `usize` to do math on it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let source = "hello, world";
    let a = &source[1..];
    let b = &source[5..];
    let diff =  b.as_ptr() as usize - a.as_ptr() as usize;
    println!("{diff}");
}
```

Comment: Might want to use an `isize` here, since `.offset(...)` expects an `isize` argument anyway; it will save you from trouble should `b` be smaller than `a`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't think that `offset` *should* be used here. Besides, OP wants to return the same thing as `str::find`, which would be `Option<usize>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course kind of unsafe, but if you want arithmetic, you can just cast the pointers to `usize` with `as` and subtract that.

(Note: it's not so unsafe that the compiler will actually complain.)

Comment: It's not unsafe *at all*. Pointers are just numbers. Accessing memory at an arbitrary location is unsafe.

Comment: But the result is absolute nonsense in this case if the slices aren't from the same string after all.

Comment: Certainly. But **unsafe** has a specific meaning in Rust and we shouldn't misuse the term as that will only confuse future readers.

Comment: “It's not unsafe at all. Pointers are just numbers.” → in C pointer arithmetic is a UB if the pointers point on different objects. This would qualify as unsafe as per Rust's definition of the word.

Comment: @mcarton True, me saying "pointers are just numbers" was careless wording. I'm pretty sure that this isn't *pointer arithmetic* though. Rust doesn't have pointer arithmetic (essentially the cause of your question), but you can convert a *pointer* to a *number*, at which point it's *numeric arithmetic*. I wonder what the C undefined behavior rules say about casting a pointer to a integer and then doing math on the result.

Comment: “I wonder what the C undefined behavior rules say about casting a pointer to a integer and then doing math on the result.” → So do I

Comment: @mcarton: In C (or C++) performing a subtraction on two unsigned integers is perfectly defined (it returns the result of mathematical subtraction, wrapping if necessary). The origin of the value (be it a pointer, user input, or whatever) fortunately does not affect the result of the operation.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Does that mean that given `void *a = ...; void *b = ...;`, then `a - b` may be UB, but `((size_t)a) - ((size_t)b)` can never be UB?

Comment: @Shepmaster: As far as I know, yes. It's just maths. There is, however, no guarantee that the result is any kind of useful. (1) you should be using `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` to get an integral type wide enough to accommodate a pointer value and (2) since `uintptr_t` is not guaranteed to be the *exact* size of a pointer, if the result wraps around it can be totally useless... and that's even before introducing the exotic segmented architecture, which I don't know much about :/

Comment: In particular, C gives you no guarantee that `(ptrdiff_t)((size_t)a) - (size_t)b) == a - b`.

Comment: It's true that pointers aren't "just numbers", but it is absolutely true that pointers *cast to numbers* are "just numbers" for the purpose of doing arithmetic. (Though I believe compilers do sometimes track pointer provenance even through such casts, so arguably they're not "just numbers" if they're ever cast *back* to pointers.)