# How to get the index of an element in a vector using pointer arithmetic?

Tags: pointers, vector, rust

In C you can use the pointer offset to get index of an element within an array, e.g.:

```
index = element_pointer - &vector[0];
```

Given a reference to an element in an array, this should be possible in Rust too.

While Rust has the ability to get the memory address from vector elements, convert them to `usize`, then subtract them - is there a more convenient/idiomatic way to do this in Rust?

Comment: This is similar to *[How to get the byte offset between `&str`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268529/how-to-get-the-byte-offset-between-str)* where the answer was “just convert to `usize`”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, given the issues which people have brought up with the pointers and stuff; the best way, imho, to do this is:

```
fn index_of_unchecked<T>(slice: &[T], item: &T) -> usize {
    if ::std::mem::size_of::<T>() == 0 {
        return 0; // do what you will with this case
    }
    (item as *const _ as usize - slice.as_ptr() as usize)
    / std::mem::size_of::<T>()
}

// note: for zero sized types here, you
// return Some(0) if item as *const T == slice.as_ptr()
// and None otherwise
fn index_of<T>(slice: &[T], item: &T) -> Option<usize> {
    let ptr = item as *const T;
    if
        slice.as_ptr() < ptr && 
        slice.as_ptr().offset(slice.len()) > ptr
    {
        Some(index_of_unchecked(slice, item))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

although, if you want methods:

```
trait IndexOfExt<T> {
    fn index_of_unchecked(&self, item: &T) -> usize;
    fn index_of(&self, item: &T) -> Option<usize>;
}

impl<T> IndexOfExt<T> for [T] {
    fn index_of_unchecked(&self, item: &T) -> usize {
        // ...
    }
    fn index_of(&self, item: &T) -> Option<usize> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and then you'll be able to use this method for any type that `Deref`s to `[T]`

Comment: I would generally recommend a `debug_assert` in `index_of_unchecked`.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a simpler way.  I think the reason is that it would be hard to guarantee that any operation or method that gave you that answer only allowed you to use it with the a `Vec` (or more likely slice) and something inside that collection; Rust wouldn't want to allow you to call it with a reference into a different vector.

More idiomatic would be to avoid needing to do it in the first place. You can't store references into `Vec` anywhere very permanent away from the `Vec` anyway due to lifetimes, so you're likely to have the index handy when you've got the reference anyway.

In particular, when iterating, for example, you'd use the [`enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) to iterate over pairs `(index, &item)`.

Comment: Enumerate is fine for the common case, however there are times where a function may (in a special case) - need to get the parent, then remove a reference from a vector. Where passing an index along is possible but inconvenient.