# How can I process data by newlines until I find two newlines in a row, then process all of the remaining data?

Tags: split, rust

I have a `Vec<u8>` which I want to split on `\n` and process it line-by-line. At some point there is a blank line and I want to process the entire rest of the vector in one chunk (not line-by-line). This sort of thing is common in HTTP or in Git commit objects.

For example:

```
key: value
otherkey: othervalue

This is the content
that is now just a big
block. I don't care about
newlines here.
```

Is there an elegant way to parse that with Rust? I can split it like this:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let data: Vec<u8> = "key: value\notherkey: othervalue\n\nThis is the content\nthat is now just a big\nblock. I don't care about\nnewlines here.".as_bytes().to_owned();

    for line in data.split(|&c| c == '\n' as u8) {
        println!("Line: {:?}", line);
        if line.len() == 0 {
            // Start of message...
        } else {
            // Header
        }
    }
}
```

However when I get to the `\n\n` I can't find a way to say "give me the rest of the `Vec` from here". It would be easy if there were a form of `split()` that returned slices with indices, instead of the actual contents, but I can't seem to find one.

Is there an elegant way to do this that doesn't just split the message and then rejoin it together?

Answer (score 2):

You can trivially get the length of each slice, tracking the current offset and do the final slice yourself:

```
static DATA: &[u8] = br#"key: value
otherkey: othervalue

This is the content
that is now just a big
block. I don't care about
newlines here.
"#;

pub fn main() {
    let mut offset = 0;

    for line in DATA.split(|&c| c == '\n' as u8) {
        offset += line.len() + 1; // Include the newline.
        if line.len() == 0 {
            break;
        } else {
            // Header
            println!("{:?}", line);
        }
    }

    let body = &DATA[offset..];
    println!("{:?}", body);
}
```

See also:

- [How to get the byte offset between `&str`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38268529/155423)