# How do I trim a slice and get the indices (indexes) of the result?

Tags: pointers, rust, slice

This seems like a **simple problem**:

```rust
let slice = " some  wacky text.   ";
let trimmed = slice.trim();
// how do I get the index of the start and end within the original slice?
```

#### Attempt 1

Look for an alternative API. `trim` wraps [`trim_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_matches) which deals with indices internally anyway: so lets copy this code! **But** this uses [`std::str::pattern::Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html) which is unstable, thus can't be used outside `std` in stable Rust.

#### Attempt 2

Just use `trim` and calculate the slice indices from the pointers. There's a nice [`as_ptr_range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_ptr_range) method, but its also unstable; luckily as the PR says there's an easy work-around.

```rust
let slice_ptr = slice.as_ptr();
let trimmed_ptr = trimmed.as_ptr();
// don't bother about the end (we can use trimmed.len())
```

Now that we've *got* some pointers, we need their difference. [`sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.sub) is *not* the right method for this. [`offset_from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.offset_from) is, but it's unstable (as noted in the design, it's only valid use is to compare two pointers into the same slice, which is exactly what we want to do, unfortunately it's yet another thing delayed by the details).

Now, there *are* hackier ways of solving this problem. We could transmute the pointers to `usize` (we know the element size is 1 byte, so no need to multiply). But this is most likely the Undefined Behaviour type of unsafe, so lets not go there.

#### Attempt 3

**Edit**: the source problem is easy to solve directly, so probably the answer in this case is roll-my-own. Possibly I should just close this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the byte offset between \`&str\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268529/how-to-get-the-byte-offset-between-str)

Comment: All answers are either unstable or rely on UB, and in any case are covered above. But it is certainly related :-)